# console is not defined - JSNI

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I have tried both

```
console.log(message);
$wnd.console.log(message);
```

However, I am still getting:

```
console is undefined
```

or

```
$wnd.console is undefined
```

When executing my application JSNI method. How can I fix this?

Comment: firefox. It seems that when firebug is not on, this error is thrown. I fixed it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like with Firefox, Firebug should be turned-on otherwise this error is thrown when `console` is called from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should use java.util.Logger.

```
Logger logger = Logger.get("");

logger.log(Level.WARNING,"This is a warning");
```

This logger will also print out to the browser log.

Comment: I observed that, logger.log() is logging in the console of Eclipse rather than browser log.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging and enable the {{ConsoleLogHandler}} and/or {{FirebugLogHandler}}.

Answer (score -1):

Open browser console first. (Press F12)

If `$wnd.console` run before you open browser console. You will get error message `$wnd.console is undefined`.

Comment: This adds little to the answer of xybrek and is not an answer on its own right. Please note, that SO is *not* a discussion board.